# D7 - Multilingual in the admin, only one language for the users

Tags: i18n-l10n

We have a drupal 7 with the following need :

- When the user visit the website, we let drupal chose the best language for the user
- He can then choose to chose another language.
- We have a finite number of language (5 so far)
- Unless he decide to change the language for the whole website, he should only see the content written in the selected language
- all user (except admins) on the website are anonymous (no registration, no login)
- we need the admins to see all languages.
- contents can exist in one or many languages. There is no "reference" language that holds all the contents.

So far we have set the language switcher for all languages, but then on the website the menu for all languages are displayed (which we don't want). Also, search is made on content for all languages. If we set the language switcher to only use the selected language, everything works as intented on the website but then the admin can only see the content matching the current selected language. We need that he sees all content.

We've been looking into some options (including the [Administration Language](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language), but unless we overlooked some configuration, it doesn't seem to fit our needs).

Any ideas, hints or suggestion welcome !

Comment: What about setting the language switcher to show all languages but hiding it from the anonymous user and only showing it to the admin?

Comment: Our main issue is that the admin has to switch between the various languages to see all contents. We would like to have the full list.

Comment: What do you mean have the full list?  You mean something beyond what the language switcher block provides?

Comment: the full list of all contents. In a way, the language switcher block is useless to us because the admin should not have to use it and the user should not be able to use it directly.

Comment: You could set this up in Views by using separate view modes for admin/anonymous users.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: We thought about it but we worry that we forget something on a page that won't show up while we code but that the client will encouter it when using its site (and thank you Patrick for all your suggestions so far !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up writing various custom modules to solve that issue.

Comment: Although I agree that Drupal still has a lot to do on the i18n side, I was surprised you had this sort of problems displaying full list of all contents. I used admin views+vbo, then modified the view by adding language field to the table. Have you tried that?

Comment: Its not because its wrong to write a custom module, But I agree with Patrick Kenny about Views taking care of this and then making a config. permissions on who can see what.